# How to handle value change of dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am using data binding between 2 properties (the binding target is dependency property). If I change the value of binding source, binding target is also changed (the value of dependency property). My question is: How can I handle the value change of dependency property?

Edit: Here is how I register my dependency property:

```
public static DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    ItemsPropertyName,
    typeof(List<ModelItem>),
    typeof(CentralPanel),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnItemsChanged));
```

So when I put breakpoint in OnItemsChanged, the method runs only once, when the value of binging source is set for the first time. Then, when I change the value of binding source, value of binding target is also changed, but OnItemsChanged does not fire, why?

Comment: When you say _I change the value of binding source_ you change whole list or item within the list?

Comment: @dkozl: I change the whole list. Does it makes any difference?

Comment: `OnItemsChanged` will trigger only if you set it to different instance of `List<ModelItem>`. It will not trigger if it will be the same list of you add or remove items from the list

Comment: @dkozl: I am actually clearing the list and add new elements. I will try will making new instance of List<ModelItem>...

Comment: @dkozl: Unfortunately it does not makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am actually clearing the list and add new elements

`OnItemsChanged` will trigger only if you set it to different instance of `List<ModelItem>`. It will not trigger if it will be the same list of you add or remove items from the list.

If you want your list notify UI with changes when you add/remove items it must implement [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface or you can use ready implementation [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `List<T>`.

If you want to catch changes to collection in code you can subscribe to [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654934%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event

> Occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed.

You can do it in `OnItemsChanged` callback:

```
private void OnItemsChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var oldList = e.OldValue as ObservableCollection<ModelItem>;
   if (oldList != null) oldList.CollectionChanged -= MyCollectionChangedCallback;
   var newList = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<ModelItem>;
   if (newList != null) newList.CollectionChanged += MyCollectionChangedCallback;
}
```

Comment: How to subscribe to CollectionChanged event? My standard way of catching changes (breakpoint in OnItemChanged) method does not work, even now, when the new instance of object is set as a value and I changed binding source and target to ObservableCollection instead of List.

Comment: When you use `ObservableCollection` you keep using only one instance and it notifies UI when items are added/removed. So when you do `var myList = new ObservableCollection<ModelItem>(); myList.CollectionChanged += MyCollectionChangedCallback;` it calls `MyCollectionChangedCallback` every time when you add/remove items in your collection

Comment: Ok, I see. But remember that setting the value of myList is done only on binding source side. So I can set this callback there, but it will be useless. So do I need to create this callback on binding target site?

Comment: You can do it in `OnItemsChanged`. In the event use `e.NewValue` and it would be good if you also unsubscribe from `e.OldValue` (if assigned)

Comment: Let me examine this one more closely. It seems that this callback fires when the Items property is 'not accessible because it is used by other thread'...

Comment: If I have my property (my binding source) called Items. And Items = _items. So what I found out, is that OnItemsChanged event runs not, when we perform Items.Add() method, but on _items.Add(). So I am able to check what value was sent. But, how can I know, where is the beginning and end of setting value now? :/ I tried to prepare collection tmpCollection, and then assign it to _items, like: _items = tmpCollection; But in this case event don't rise. I think I need to use different method than _items.Add(), so I will send all items at one, not iterate...

Comment: I will try with _items.AddRange(tmpCollectio, true); so I will clear collection and set value once, and event should rise once...

Comment: Ok dkozl. When I use AddRange(2 items collection, clear = true), the Items_CollectionChanged method runs 3 times. First it is not sending any value (as long as it corresponds to clearing collection), then twice with values. It seems that this will solve my problem. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Each grid view has a set of event functions defined in the .aspx definition of the grid view, and they are contrusted in the code behind aspx.cs of the page.

EventArgs e parameter of the event contains both definitions of **Old** and **New** Values of a certain property: **e.NewValues["PropertyName"]**. this property helps you handle the changed value of your dependcy property.

Regards,
ANDOURA

Comment: Yes, that's right. But problem is, that OnItemsChanged, where I can check the value of e, runs only once. So it shows me e.NewValue as a value and e.OldValue as a null. I am sure, that next time when it runs, it will override OldValue, but the problem is, that Event runs only once :)

Comment: try using the following even **OnItemsSourceChanged** :

 `public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty

            = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ItemsControl), 

                                          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((IEnumerable)null, 

                                                                        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourceChanged)));

  

        private static void **OnItemsSourceChanged**(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)`
{
**e.Old** and **e.New** 
}